# Rich Text Editor target for mailto links

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

Using `Sitecore 8.2`, when I add a `mailto:` link, it gives me a **validation error** that *external links require a target*.

However, the modal tab for mailto links doesn't contain a target field, and if I insert something into the Hyperlink tab it either ignores it or uses just the fields on that tab - ie it won't seem to pull from multiple tabs - this is when I confirm by going into edit html.

I'm wondering if there is any way of doing this other than manually editing the html or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a link via the `Hyperlink Manager` you should have an `Email` tab. When you use this tab, the correct link `<a href="mailto:info@address.com">Email me</a>` will be generated. See also the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/insert-a-link-in-a-text-field.html

[image]

Comment: Yes, but part of the problem is that the external link validation rule is getting activated because this mailto link does not have a target.  I can remove the validation rule (I have) but I find it odd that the UI creates html that is then flagged by this validation rule...

Comment: @LeviWallach that is indeed odd. Another workaround is to first use the Hyperlink tab to set a link with a fake url and a target. Then you should edit the link again but now use the E-Mail tab to set the emailaddress. The previously set target will remain in the HTML while the url gets changed to the mailto:addres value. The External Link Validator checks whether a targer OR a title (tooltip) has been set.

Comment: Yeah, since this is something that the customer needs to use, it seems not worth it if we need to instruct them to do this...  Thanks.